# "How are" or "How is" the wife and kid?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subject-verb-inversion, compound-subjects

> 1. How are the wife and kid?
> 2. How is the wife and kid?

Which is more correct?

Answer (score 10):

"Are" is correct for most compound subjects, except for singular meanings (i.e. mac and cheese is) and alternative subjects (you or your wife is -- you or your friends are, though -- matches subject closest to the verb).
Yay for style manuals.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a question of "more" correct.  The first (using "are") is correct, and the second (using "is") is not.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you shouldn't say "**How is** the wife and kid(s)." It's neither idiomatic, nor generally considered grammatical in standard English.

"**How are** the wife and kid(s)" would be considered grammatical, for the reasons [Gamileon](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28604/are-vs-is-with-compound-subjects#) gave (compound subjects are generally treated as plural).

The most idiomatic way of saying this, though, is "**How's** the wife and kid(s)" with the contraction "How's". Unlike "How is", "How's" is commonly used with a plural subject. Pedants may call this ungrammatical, but it's a well-established feature of English idiom, and since this expression is fairly idiomatic and colloquial I don't think it's a problem if you use idiomatic but nonstandard grammar.

Check out this chart from the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=How%20are%20the%20wife%20and%2C%20How%20is%20the%20wife%20and%2C%20How's%20the%20wife%20and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHow%20are%20the%20wife%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHow%20%27s%20the%20wife%20and%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

For more information on structures like "How's" with a plural subject, see my answer to the following question: *[Use of "Here's" before a plural noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359055/use-of-heres-before-a-plural-noun/359065#359065)*

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, a useful test involves substituting pronouns. Consider

> How is they?

versus

> How are they?

Say the wife and kid live in different places—maybe the latter is away at school—and you want to express this independence, you might use

> How is the wife? The kid?

Any more explicit and the repetitiveness will be tiresome.